# How to access matched dataset after using `CBPS` package of R?

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I am using `CBPS` package of R for propensity score matching of a dataset with a two levels treatment group.
This the code I wrote:

```
fit <- CBPS(formula=formu1, data = data2, ATT = TRUE, twostep = FALSE, standardize = TRUE)
    
rr.att.CBPS <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=fitted(fit), M=1, ties=FALSE, replace=FALSE, estimand='ATT')
```

But, how can I access the matched dataset for analysis?

Comment: Please read this about [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are likely to get help if you improve your question.

Comment: just check the documents for the matching function you are using. speaking of which, the CBPS package imports the [MatchIt](https://github.com/cran/CBPS/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L25) package but you seem to be using `Matching::Match`

Comment: Please follow the guidelines about [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I formatted your code for you. You need to add the missing `library(CBPS)` statement. to make it reproducible As to accessing those objects, read the package doc(/quickstart/examples), try out some code, post the code and where you got stuck. And to make your code reproducible, use one of the builtin datasets like iris , diamonds, mtcars etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `MatchIt` package instead.
Imagine a dataset called 'dataset' with a binary treatment group(T) and some other covariates (V1,V2,V3) , and a target variable(p).

```
install.packages("MatchIt")   #if not installed before
library("MatchIt")     #importing MatchIt

# Formula for matching(include other covariates which treatment groups will be matched based on them, eg. V1 & V2)
formula <- "T ~ V1+V2"
formula <- as.formula(formula)    #making formula format

#implementing matching process with nearest neighbour method with 2:1 ratio by logistic regression
matched_data <- matchit(formula, method = "nearest", ratio = 2, data = dataset, link = "logit")

# assigning matched data to a variable which then can be used for further analysis such as regression
final_matched <- match.data(mached_data)


# Absolute standardized mean difference plot of variables used to match for assessment of balance before and after matching
plot(summary(matched_data))
```

Comment: plot(summary(final_matched))        gives the following error                                                                                
 Error in tabulate(Ind[, dimd]) : 'bin' must be numeric or a factor

Comment: @PhDFin , You are right, that was a mistake because of variables name similarity.You should put 'matchit' object in summary, so this the correct one: plot(summary(matched_data))

Comment: This does not answer the question because it does not use CBPS, which the OP asked about. The code just estimates logistic regression propensity scores. Also, the argument `family = binomial("logit")` does nothing because `matchit()` doesn't accept `family` as an argument.

Comment: @Noah, ok, you are right, It should be 'link' instead of 'family'. But the code worked and solved OP issues. That's the point. Matching was the problem, not just using the package, We use R for analysis, not for learning packages.